# My Android emulator appears over sized and the screen is in the top left corner

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

My android emulator on android studio is over sized and the screen is distorted and located in the top left corner with the rest of the phone appearing black.

Previously it worked fine with all apps run from VS Code and Android Studio. However recently it just got weird. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio as well as remove all files related to Android Studio with no fix, i have also resized the Emulator with no fix to the problem.

[image: Its best you see what i mean]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use another emulator because i used to be like that

Comment: Which other emulator can you recommend?

Comment: you can try [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)